# How do I uninstall Visual Studio 2012 Update 2?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I installed VS2012 and then I updated to VS2012 Update 2, so my Visual Studio version would be 11.0.60315.01 Update 2.

But now I want to revert to 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL. How can I uninstall the update?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Updates to Visual Studio are implemented as Windows updates, much like Office and other Microsoft suites. Once you know this, it immediately becomes obvious where to look. (Of course, the difficult part is knowing in the first place...)

You can find the update by visiting the **Programs** control panel category, and choosing **View installed updates** under the Programs and Features subcategory:

[image]

Alternatively, from the Windows Update control panel, choose **View update history** in the task pane, then click **Installed Updates** in the update history page.

Either option takes you to the same list of updates; most VS2012 updates should be listed under the **Microsoft Visual Studio 2012** update category.

Comment: I would give you 1,000 upvotes if I could, the Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 completely messed up my projects (since the compiler update saw some good code I needed as erroneous). I looked in the 'Installed Programs' and couldn't find it there, then read your post and the update is no more. A real big thanks! :-)

Comment: I agree with cybermonkey. Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 came and with it my CPU started maxing out whenever I used a web project. Made VS unusable. Removing the update made me productive again.

Comment: @Josh Same here guys, please check out my bug report and vote it up ... https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1030904/ever-since-update-4-earlier-today-vs-2013-is-slow

Comment: I just installed Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 and whenever I try to run a project, I get the error "The debugger resource DLL is out of date. If this problem persists, use 'Add or Remove Programs' in control panel to repair your visual studio installation." I ran the repair tool twice and it didn't fix the issue. Going to remove this update...

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, uninstalling VS 2013 Upd 5 had not restored my TFS server Upd 4 which had been ruined by it. (Launching TFS repair after that did not made it work again either... Trying to reinstall vs upd 5 then upgrading TFS to upd 5...) So beware, even if it is supposed to be uninstallable, you may not recover from some bad side effects those update are able to cause.

Comment: @Frederic: Yeah :( In that case System Restore is probably your best bet - the good news is that the installer will always create a restore point prior to each update.

Comment: Ok thanks, but since pushing it all to Upd 5 had finally fixed things, well, I will not try System Restore to confirm it works. (Anyway, one big part of the trouble in my case is that at my work, we are all devs without any sys adm for handling systems with robust procedures.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! VS2015 update 1 screwed up C++ 64bit debugging completely - instead of local it always runs remote debugger for some reason... :(

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the Visual studio updates , such as VS2013.3 , VS2013.5 , VSK**** . and restart it. normally it will be ok. you could find update . windows-> control Panle  ->  program and feature -> update -> select VS2013 update -> uninstall it.

Regards,