# How to download Visual Studio 2015 community without update 1?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I need Visual Studio 2015 Community edition without the update 1, but I can't find it anywhere. Been searching Microsofts pages but all downloads just points to the latest version which includes update 1 (and I want the older tools included before the update 1 came).

Can anyone help?

Comment: One word question: Why? (this will affect answers: eg. if you want to work around an issue introduced by Update 1 there may be better ways.)

Comment: I'm attending the microsoft developer roadshow and the requirements says that the course material will not work with update 1.

Comment: How hard did you look? Based on the publication date [this is RTM](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48146).

Comment: Bah, I never get the hang of all the abbreviations so RTM means the first version? :)

Comment: "Release to Manufacturing" (from the days when one received piles of floppies), these days also "RTW" (Release to Web). But, yes, the initial release.

Comment: Web installer for that doesn't work though... still points to "Visual Studio 2015 Update 1". I'll try the iso and hope that doesn't check the web before installing as well :(

Comment: @Richard, MSVC 2015 Update 1 has a known regression causing C1001 internal compiler errors with one of the libraries I use. The library has a fix, but it won't be available as a stable release for a while.

For reference, the library bug report is [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=1096).

Comment: Since this was asked, I've installed VS2015 Enterprise on a system. With a RTM installer (downloaded at that time). It prompted to include Update 1, but it did appear to be optional (I didn't have time to confirm this).

Answer (score 1):

In [answering another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16557620/2288986), @BoltClock explains that you can uninstall individual updates via the View Installed Updates window in the Control Panel.

You can install VS with the update and then *try* uninstalling the update via the Control Panel. I don't know that it will work, so if it does, come back and comment. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is. I found this on microsoft download website.

Detail

Name : VS 2015'without update'.iso

Size : 3.7 GB

Download link :
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48146

Comment: http://imgur.com/NKdobub

Here you can see.VS size is 3.7GB.
VS update 3 sized ~ 7GB.

Answer (score 0):

If update 3 is already installed into the machine, needs to uninstall it from control panel -> View installed updates.

Fresh installation without any update can be done by steps in following URL.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt653628.aspx